# Magento : Remove Free Product from Cart on Applying Coupon Code

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, quoteitem

All the Free products need to remove from cart if customer apply coupon code. Actual product should remain same in cart. 
I do have specific category for free products.

Help me to figure it out how to achieve this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to used magento event observer to archive this.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - Can u please explain it little bit more to me? It would be great if u share me some code reference.. Thanks

Comment: I post answer, please check.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Thanks. :) Let me try that code.

Comment: sure, If answer help accept so it will help other in community as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an observer on `sales_quote_collect_totals_after`

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
      <observers>
        <[namespace]_[modulename]_sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>[Module]_[Namespace]_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>salesQuoteCollectTotalsAfter</method>
        </[namespace]_[modulename]_sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
      </observers>
    </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
</events>
```

In your `observer.php` use

```
class [Module]_[Namespace]_Model_Observer
{
   salesQuoteCollectTotalsAfter($observer)
   {
       $quote = $observer->getQuote();
       $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
       $couponcode = $quote->getData('coupon_code');
       if ($couponcode == '[YOUR_COUPON_CODE]') {
            foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item):
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $item->getSku());
                $cartProductCatId = $_product->getCategoryIds();
                    if(is_array($cartProductCatId) && in_array('[YOUR_CATEGORY_ID]',$cartProductCatId)){
                        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
                    }
            endforeach;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used magento event observer in your custom extension like.

```
  vendor\extension\etc\config.xml

<global>
  <events>
    <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
      <observers>
        <vendor_extension_sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>vendor_extension_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>salesQuoteCollectTotalsAfter</method>
        </vendor_extension_sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
      </observers>
    </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
  </events>
</global>
```

Now create Observer file.

```
vendor\extension\Model\Observer.php

class vendor_extension_Model_Observer
{
   salesQuoteCollectTotalsAfter($observer)
   {
       $quote = $observer->getQuote();
       $couponcode = $quote->getData('coupon_code');
       if ($couponcode != '') {
          /**
           * Your custom code here to remove free item
           */
       }
       return $this;
   }
}
```